# How to check if string contains specific special characters or starting with a space?

Tags: php, regex

I have a table in DB contains locations , Some of these locations contain Spanish chars like (Â , Ù) , So I can't use `[a-zA-Z0-9]`.

I want to only allow the following:

1- any amount of white spaces among words , But not at the beginning of the string , The first character will be always a-zA-Z.

2- Allow & , ' , () once in the whole string

3- Allow any amount of -

So the following will be ok:

```
word word
word-word
word & word
word'word
word(word)
word (word)
word word word
word-word-word
```

But the following will not be allowed:

```
 word                        //There is a space at the beginning
-word
& word
word'word'word or word''word //only one -
word & word & word           // only one &
word(word)(word)             //only one ()
```

The rest of the special chars like (? / < > {} [] * ^ % $ . ..etc) mustn't be allowed.

Is that possible ?

Comment: yes its possible, case closed

Comment: with regex, everything is possible... try this https://regex101.com it will help you solve your puzzle.

Comment: The question I have marked as dupe has an answer that should lead you to a solution. @nitrex makes a good suggestion too.

Comment: @vascowhite , Not working